# Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Tagging.TextMarkerTag - OnClick Event

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

Does anybody know how to capture a click on a TextMarker in an IWpfTextView? I want to have this functionality in the XML editor, to allow CTRL+Click on certain nodes. The specific nodes can be highlighted now, but there is not an "OnClick" event on a Textmarker.

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.tagging.textmarkertag.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no event on a TextMarker, you are correct. What you want to do is implement and MEF export an [IMouseProcessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.imouseprocessor.aspx), and in the appropriate methods see if you're within a span you care about. There's a class `MouseProcessorBase` you can derive from to make your implementation a bit less irritating.

Noah Richards' GoToDef sample which implements Ctrl+Click in a very similar way like you are trying to do here. The code is up at https://github.com/NoahRic/GoToDef. I'd *strongly* recommend you take a look at it.